# How to determine if Mongoose object has an ID in an array?

Tags: mongoose

How can I determine if a document's property already has an instance of another ObjectId?  I already have the document from the database so I do NOT want to hit the database again?

Example:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    friends: [ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' ]
});
```

And, I already have the User document:

```
var friendId = req.body.friendId;

User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user){
    if (!user){
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found' });
    } else {
        // DETERMINE IF 'friends' ARRAY ALREADY HAS THE friendId
        // ADD THE friendId IF IT DOES NOT EXIST
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of on the Schema and User objects but nothing works.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot just use .indexOf(friendId) as with any other array?

Comment: Of course I tried that.  It didn't work.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the ObjectId array not being initialized in the schema?  Or maybe some odd data type?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you tried `indexOf(friendId)` but that is, in fact, how to do this:

```js
var friendId = req.body.friendId;

User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user){
    if (!user){
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found' });
    } else {
        if (user.friends.indexOf(friendId) === -1) {
            // friendId is not already in user.friends; add it
        } else {
            // friendId already exists
        }
    }
}
```

Or, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, you can do it all with a single `update` that uses [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) to add `friendId` to the `friends` array, only if it's not already present:

```js
User.update(
    { email: req.body.email },
    { $addToSet: { friends: friendId } },
    function(err, count){
        if (!count){
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found' });
        }
        ...
    }
);
```

Also, it's probably just a typo, but I had to change `userSchema` to the following to make it valid:

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    friends: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } ]
});
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch. I just verified that this works too.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was wondering if there was some magic function which would insert a new value only if it did NOT already exist.